# Unity Button Delegates (AddListener)

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine, delegates

I'm trying to instantie several button using prefab.

But I've got a problem to Delegate variable.

```
for(int i = 0; i < _partnerList.partner.Count; i++)
{
    GameObject _instance_partner_button = Instantiate(_prefab_partner_button);
    _instance_partner_button.name = "_button_"+_partnerList.partner[i].partner_name;

    _instance_partner_button.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("_UI_menu_partner").transform, false);

    // Change Value of The Button ----------------------------------------------------------------
    Text _instance_partner_button_text = _instance_partner_button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
    _instance_partner_button_text.text = _partnerList.partner[i].partner_name;

    Button _instance_partner_button_button = _instance_partner_button.GetComponent<Button>();

    int _tempInt = i;

    // Delegate to Another Script ---------------------------------------------------------------
    _instance_partner_button_button.onClick.AddListener(() => _scripts_myScripts_ui.AnimationMenuPartner(_tempInt));
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

*The function AnimationMenuPartner() just Debug.Log(_tempInt);*

No matter which button I press the result is the same.

I'm maybe missing something, as I see in this link it must be working correctly [Link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/908847/passing-a-temporary-variable-to-add-listener.html)

Thanks you for your help.

Edit :

The Another Script with the function AnimationMenuPartner

```
public void AnimationMenuPartner(int _tempInt)
{
    Debug.Log(_tempInt));
}
```

The log output print : "4"

Which is the length of the list.

Comment: where is code of `AnimationMenuPartner()` method?

Comment: In another script, I'll edit the first post, but there's nothing else than the Debug.Log

Comment: Please add the Log output that you are getting as well

Comment: Done, I edited the post ;)

Comment: Press the play button and before pressing any button. Select every button from hierarchy window and check in inspector to see what values are assigned to the onClick() listners of each button

Comment: That's the thing, nothing is assigned, but every button is working and print 4 ;)

Comment: Are you doing the for loop in a coroutine function?

Comment: here is a screen [link](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=558057Untitled1.jpg), and yes I'm doing the loop in a coroutine

Comment: I don't now if that reply was to me. If it was, it didn't answer my yes or no question....

Comment: I solved the issue, I put the loop out of the coroutine function, Can you explain why it's not working in the coroutine?

Comment: I guess this is because of the way  `List` is handled in a coroutine. Something about boxing variables. Not 100 sure but this problem is well known in Unity. You now know what to do if you experience this problem again.